# Content type migration using the Feature module?

Tags: 7, features

We have to upgrade Drupal 6 site to Drupal 7. We know that we can use migrate module for importing Drupal 6 content. But I'd like to know if we can use Features module for importing content types, taxonomies and blocks from Drupal 6 to Drupal 7?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is already included in the core. You don't need to install Features in order to migrate all that.

Here's what you need to do in a nutshell: disable all contrib modules, make backups of everything, plug D7 into the D6 database and update the site. Drupal will take care of all basics, such as content types and fields.

Refer to the [documentation](https://www.drupal.org/node/1113358) for more information.